How to Share a Service Worker Between MFE PWA App and Shell Using Module Federation in React?
I have a shell application and a Micro Frontend (MFE) Progressive Web App (PWA) hosted inside the shell app. I need to share a service worker file from the PWA app and use it within the shell app. I'm using Module Federation (MF) for this purpose.
Both apps in React
How can I ensure the service worker is correctly shared and functions properly across both the shell app and the PWA app?
Are there any specific configurations or adjustments needed to make this work seamlessly?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
